# Attaching method to Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged EventHandler hangs when debugging on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

We're trying to check our host server reachability when the phone running our app's connectivity changes. We are using the ConnectivityChanged (EventHandler) in the Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity class. However, when we try to attach the Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged method to the EventHandler it just hangs.

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Run(async () => { await ApplicationContext.InitialiseAsync(); }).Wait();
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
        if (ApplicationContext.Configuration != null && ApplicationContext.Configuration.IsValid())
        {
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
            Task.Run(async () => { await ((LoginViewModel)loginPage.BindingContext).InitialiseAsync(true); }).Wait();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(loginPage);
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ConnectionPage());
        }
        ((NavigationPage)MainPage).Popped += Page_CleanUp;
    }
    private async void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DependencyService.Get<IServerReachability>().ConnectionAvailable())
        {
            await ApplicationContext.SetNetworkConnectionAsync(ConnectionState.Online);
            await ApplicationContext.RESTServiceConnectionTestAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await ApplicationContext.SetNetworkConnectionAsync(ConnectionState.Offline);
        }
    }
```

This is only an issue on iOS, when using VS for Windows, while debugging. Once the app is deployed on the iPhone, there is no issue

We created a test app:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += ApplicationContext.Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    public static async void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
```

We debugged this on Windows using a physical device and it attached the method successfully.

Comment: Hi , it seems like this not works in ios simulator . This may be a limitation of `Connectivity`, because the simulator used network is from Mac. You'd better test that in a physical device.

Comment: Hi Junior, we previously discovered the same thing. The iOS Simulator doesn't really allow connectivity changes, it's why all our testing has been on the physical device, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Yeah, It is often not compatible with some libraries or methods involving hardware api on the iOS simulator . Such as bluetooth methods also can not work in iOS simulator.